# Pulling Values from $order in Commerce Cart

Tags: entities, commerce

I am trying to pull the value of a selected item in a field list located in the order entity.  Later this is used to determine what panes should be shown in the checkout workflow.  I should note that the list is located in a checkout pane itself and therefore must be pulled from either $order->data or entity_metadata_wrapper.  I am having problems getting the test code to work on one pane, specifically with getting the selected value from the list.

```
    global $user;

// $checkout_panes actually holds ALL the panes...
foreach($checkout_panes as $pane_name => &$pane_data) {

    // load current order
    $order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);

    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
    $make = $order->field_make['und']['0']['value'];

    if($make == 'value2'){


      // ...we only need to override one of them
      if($pane_name == 'commerce_fieldgroup_pane__534' && $pane_data['enabled']) {

            // the pane is enabled by default, so we need to disable it
            $pane_data['enabled'] = 0;

      }
   }
}
```